# affect env variables to Spring boot application properties

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I am looking for a way to map my Linux server environment variables to my keys in the application properties file.

spring.mail.username={value}
spring.mail.password={value}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port={value}

{value} would come from system defined environment variables.

Comment: Let's edit your question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

OS environment variables are also taken into account by Spring Boot. You just need to name them accordingly (`SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME` for example). You can check more info on how Spring Boots reads external configuration at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could get from two ways

### Replacing properties var with environment var

If You set an enviromment var will override var on properties

Set on env

```sh
# we can override all properties var replacing  "." to "_"
SERVER_PORT=8009
```

and set on .properties

```sh
# this will be overrided by SERVER_PORT var
server.port=8001
```

### Using vars on .properties

You can use environment vars on .properties with ${name_env_var}

```sh
server.port=${SERVER_PORT_ENV:default_value_if_env_not_found}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Where should the env variables be set? In /etc/profile or /etc/environment or in a .env file?

Comment: you can do on both. How are you running your application? At any IDE you are using has a way to set enviromment variables or read some .env  file.  if are you trying on command line don't forget to export vars eg. `export VAR="value" & java -jar app.jar`